# 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'Invalid bind-variable name ':1'

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdo, mysqli, zend-db

Good day,

**Background Info:**

Client's hosting server is being upgraded from PHP 5.2 to PHP 5.3. The client's app breaks when tested on PHP 5.3. Specifically the insert and update methods are the ones which are breaking the app. The app coded in Zend Framework v1.7.2.

We have tried simply upgrading the Zend Framework core, however it seems that the previous developers made changes to the core, which causes the app to completely break when the framework has been upgraded.

**Problem**

The best solution was to add a class called AppModel which extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and then simply overwrite the insert and update methods. All models in this app extend the AppModel class. This works fine until checkbox data or radio button data has to be written to the database.

The app now throws the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with
>   message 'Invalid bind-variable name ':1'' in ....

*NB. Full error message at the bottom*

I have been looking for a solution on the internet for days in vain. One of the solutions I found was to change **Mysqli** to **Pdo_Mysql**. however it seems that there is no such class in the framework. There is the class **Pdo** which throws the same error as Mysqli.

Please help!

*Please excuse my English. If you need clarification please dont hesitate to contact me. thanks in advance*

The following is code sample from the AppModel class:

```
class AppModel extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{
                //PHP 5.3 fix   
                public function insert(array $data) {

                    //array to carry data for holding data
                    $ins_data = array();

                    foreach($data as $table => $value){
                        $ins_data['tables'][] = $table;
                        $ins_data['values'][] = mysql_escape_string($value);
                    }

                    $db = Zend_Registry::get('db');                    

                    $ins_query = ' INSERT INTO '.  $this->_name.' ('.implode($ins_data['tables'], ', ').')
                                   VALUES ("'.implode($ins_data['values'], '", "').'")'; 
                    $ins_action = new Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli($db, $ins_query);
                    $ins_action->execute();
                    return $db->lastInsertId();
                }        
}
```

Complete error message:

```
Fatal error: 
    Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' 
    with message 'Invalid bind-variable name ':1'' 
    in C:\wamp\www\schoolnet\public_html\Zend\Db\Statement.php:143 
Stack trace: 
#0 C:\wamp\www\schoolnet\public_html\Zend\Db\Statement.php(108): Zend_Db_Statement->_parseParameters(' UPDATE user_te...') 
#1 C:\wamp\www\schoolnet\application\AppModel.php(43): Zend_Db_Statement->__construct(Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli), ' UPDATE user_te...') 
#2 C:\wamp\www\schoolnet\application\modules\user\helpers\UserHelper.php(530): AppModel->update(Array, 'user_id = 6') 
#3 C:\wamp\www\schoolnet\application\modules\user\controllers\UserController.php(533): user_helpers_UserHelper->teacherUpdate(Array, 6) 
#4 C:\wamp\www\schoolnet\application\modules\user\controllers\UserController.php(300): UserController->teacherUpdateDetails(Array, 6) 
#5 C:\wamp\www\schoolnet\public_html\Zend\Controller\Action.php(503): UserController->detailseditAction() 
#6 C:\wamp\www\schoolnet\public_html\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(285): Zend_Control in C:\wamp\www\schoolnet\public_html\Zend\Db\Statement.php on line 143
```

Comment: It would help if you posted the output from `Zend_Debug::Dump($data)` or `echo $ins_query` inside the `insert` method.

Comment: Problem solved by using single quotes instead of double quotes in the SQL query string like the example: `$ins_query = ' INSERT INTO '.  $this->_name.' ('.implode($ins_data['tables'], ', ').')
                                   VALUES (\''.implode($ins_data['values'], '\', \'')`